# Issues with making a connection to the MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

so I keep getting the following error message on my register.php page. My hosting provider says it that its the version of php by I have tried from 7.1 all the way down to 5.6 and still the same thing. Below is the error that keeps appearing.

> Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to int in /home/scylla97/public_html/register.php on line 74

Please see code below on register.php page.

---

```
            if ($securimage->check($_POST['captcha_code']) == false) {
                echo '<font color="white">Wrong captcha :\ </font>';
        }
        else {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $rpassword = $_POST['rpassword'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $errors = array();
        $checkUsername = $odb -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username");
        $checkUsername -> execute(array(':username' => $username));
        $countUsername = $checkUsername -> fetchColumn(0);
        if ($checkUsername > 0)
        {
            $errors['<font color="white">Username is already taken</font>'];
        }
        if (!ctype_alnum($username) || strlen($username) < 4 || strlen($username) > 15)
        {
            $errors[] = '<font color="white">Username Must Be  Alphanumberic And 4-15 characters in length</font>';
        }
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        {
            $errors[] = '<font color="white">Email is invalid</font>';
        }
        if (empty($username) || empty($password) || empty($rpassword) || empty($email))
        {
            $errors[] = '<font color="white">Please fill in all fields</font>';
        }
        if ($password != $rpassword)
        {
            $errors[] = '<font color="white">Passwords do not match</font>';
        }
        if (empty($errors))
        {
             try{ 
            $insertUser = $odb -> prepare("INSERT INTO `users` VALUES(NULL, :username, :password, :email, 0, 0, 0, 0)");
            $insertUser -> execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => SHA1($password), ':email' => $email));
            } 
            catch(PDOException $exception){ 
               return $exception->getMessage(); 
            } 
            echo '<div class="nNote nSuccess hideit"><p><strong><font color="white">SUCCESS: </font></strong><font color="white">User has been registered.  Redirecting....</font></p></div><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=login.php">';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<div class="nNote nFailure hideit"><p><strong>ERROR:</strong><br />';
            foreach($errors as $error)
            {
                echo '-'.$error.'<br />';
            }
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
    }
    ?>
```

---

Would really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Where is line 74?

Comment: `phpMyAdmin` is a tool written in PHP for maintaining a MySQL database. It is not a database and you dont connect to it

Comment: this is 2017. Do not do this `SHA1($password)`

Comment: `$checkUsername` is a PDOStatement. `$countUsername` contains your count!!!!!!

Comment: Thank you everybody for your assistance. Apologies, I am still learning php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$checkUsername = $odb -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username");
        $checkUsername -> execute(array(':username' => $username));//OOP 101 suggests that $checkUsername gets all functions/methods contained via the `$odb` variable  

 $countUsername = $checkUsername -> fetchColumn(0);// use this variable in your if statements.
```

`$checkUsername` is merely the statement.It cannot be used on its own to check for `count`

Change your if conditions to

```
if ($countUsername > 0)
        {
            $errors['<font color="white">Username is already taken</font>'];
        }
```

Comment: Pleasure @user3657631

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a `PDOStatement` `$checkUsername` with an integer (in this case you chek if it's greater than 0) while in fact, the count of rows is stored in `$countUsername`, so you need to change your code to:

```
    if ($countUsername> 0)
    {
        $errors['<font color="white">Username is already taken</font>'];
    }
```

Obs: Not allowed to comment